# What does ON UPDATE RESTRICT do?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

```
...
user_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT fk_user_meta FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT
```

I know from [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php) that ON DELETE CASCADE means that if I delete a row from the users table, then the associated row from the user meta table will be removed too. But what does  ON UPDATE RESTRICT do?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`RESTRICT` prevents the action from happening if there's any foreign keys that rely on the field that's being changed.

Comment: why would you ever want to implement that?

Comment: @Blauhirn If you have data in other tables that don't make sense without the referenced data, then allowing its deletion and the data to get into an invalid state would be a bad idea. `RESTRICT` allows you to delete data referred to by a foreign key only if no other data relies on it. e.g. deleting a customer record when there are customer orders referring to it. A customer who has made no orders could be safely deleted.

Comment: Sounds nice to have. Does it have much of a performance cost?

Comment: @WillSheppard- Better off thinking about the cost of not doing it